# I am not getting all URL from chrome in Winform .NET Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-framework-version

I am getting only title Names from all opened tab in chrome. (I need all URL from all Tabs of Chrome).
The following code shows the Title names of all the Tab But I need URL for All the Tabs.

```
private static void CheckForURL()
        {
            Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Chrome is not running");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
                {
                    // the chrome process must have a window 
                    if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // to find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button 
                    AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                    Condition condNewTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "New 
                    Tab");
                    AutomationElement elmNewTab = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condNewTab);
                    // get the tabstrip by getting the parent of the 'new tab' button 
                    TreeWalker treewalker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
                    AutomationElement elmTabStrip = treewalker.GetParent(elmNewTab);
                    // loop through all the tabs and get the names which is the page title 
                    Condition condTabItem = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, 
                    ControlType.TabItem);
                    foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in elmTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, 
                    condTabItem))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(tabitem.Current.Name);                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```